# How do you get a Microsoft Access form to refresh a computed column?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, data-binding

I have a Microsoft Access form that is bound to a linked SQL Server table that has a computed column.  I have a control bound to the computed column.

I already realize that the computed field cannot be refreshed until AFTER a record is saved.  Beyond that, what is the best way to refresh that textbox that is bound to the computed column after save.

I would prefer not to do a me.requery (a requery of the whole recordset).

Is there a way to JUST refresh that one field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDITED FOR CLARITY:  There are actually a few strategies to consider.**

*Form.Refresh()* will refresh your Form's recordsource capturing modifications and deletions to existing records and will stay positioned on the current record. However, you would not see any NEW records that were added since you opened your form.

*Form.Requery()* will re-run the Form's recordsource query. You will see all the Form.Refresh() changes AND it will show you any new records. On the UI, Form.Requery() repositions to the first record.

*Form.Control.Requery()* is similar to Form.Refresh() in that you will not change record position or see NEW records.  It will update your control, assuming the control is based on a query/table.

You'll need to be sure that the triggering event involves a database update.  There can be cases where the control's AfterUpdate() precedes database I/O, which wouldn't help you.

Comment: I believe that for a bound field where the calculation is in the underlying recordsource, or, as in this case, a view on the server, there is no difference between Requery and Refresh. Requery *is* useful if you're calculating the control in the form itself.

Comment: See my answer below for my exact resolution.  This set me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys.  Here it what worked.

In the Form AfterUpdate event I did a Me.ControlName.Requery.  This was perfect as it did not do a complete form refresh or requery.

I just experimented with different event/method combinations until I got the best result.

Thanks for the input.

Seth

Answer (score 1):

2016 (related) Answer:  In Access 2016, I have a control that is a calculated field based on values in 4 other bound textboxes.  I set the Control Source for the calculated field to be `=gsngCalculatePaymentAmount([txtInterestRate],[txtLengthOfLoanInYears],[txtSalePrice],[txtMoneyDown])`.

But I needed the value to be refreshed whenever ANY of the values for any of those 4 textboxes changed.  Had difficulty in making the calculated value refresh.  SOLUTION:  In the AfterUpdate event in EACH of the 4 textboxes whose value was being used for the calculated field, I simply did the following:

```
Dim v1 As Variant
v1 = Me.txtMyCalculatedTextbox
```

Simply referencing the value of the calculated field resolved it!
Rex

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .Refresh for either the underlying recordset, or for the bound control? I would expect it to work for a Jet/ACE back end, but the interaction with different database server back ends is going to be non-predictable.

There might also be an interaction with you ODBC refresh interval, but I would expect a manual refresh in code to take care of that.

Where to call it is another issue -- I would assume the appropriate place would be in the AfterUpdate events of the controls bound to the fields the calculation is based on. But you might have to save the record for the server-side calculation to happen -- Refresh alone might or might not do the trick. I know with Jet/ACE data sources a Refresh saves the record, but I don't know for certain if it behaves the same way with ODBC data sources.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way (the control source of `txtTextBox` is an SQL Server field whose value is computed):

```
On Error Goto ErrorHandler


'After saving data when I wanted to see the updated value of computed field

txtTextBox = txtTextBox & ""

ErrorHandler: If err.Number = -2147352567 Then 'The data has been changed.

                            Resume Next

                  else

                      msgbox  err.description

               end if
```