# Access 2010 subform requery not working but did in 2003?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, subform

I am trying to figure out why a subform Requery is NOT showing changed records (or new or deleted for that matter) in Access 2010/2007, when it worked in 2003?

If I close/reopen the form, that values are correct but not until then?
Has something changed in 2007/2010 that requires an additional step?

This is a subform used by multiple forms - and I am NOT trying to refresh/requrey based on anything happening on the main form, etc.
There is a button on the SUBform that makes this call to move a record UP (re order the rows);

The database is SQL Server 2005, not local access if that makes any difference.

```
Private Sub btnUp_Click()
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
Dim blnUpdateSwitch As Boolean
    blnUpdateSwitch = False
Dim blnRemoval As Boolean
    blnRemoval = False

' Commit any outstanding edits before moving the records.

Me.Refresh

Dim intCurrentRecord As Integer
intCurrentRecord = Me.CurrentRecord
If Me.Recordset!blnSwitch = True Then blnUpdateSwitch = True
If intCurrentRecord >= 2 Then
    Me.Recordset.Edit
    Me.Recordset!lngSequence = intCurrentRecord - 1
    Me.Recordset.Update

    Me.Recordset.MovePrevious

    Me.Recordset.Edit
    Me.Recordset!lngSequence = intCurrentRecord
    Me.Recordset.Update

    Me.Recordset.Requery
    If blnUpdateSwitch Then CalculateSwitchOrder

    Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition = intCurrentRecord - 2

    Me.Requery

End If

Exit Sub

Error_Handler:

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through the code line by line to see what's happening?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "see whats happening"?
I can step through, with no errors, etc.
The grid/table "cursor" on the form moves to the correct row on screen, but the value still shows the old value ?

In access 2003 the value updated onscreen. In 2010 it does not - so I wasn't sure if I need to do something additional etc.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637722/how-do-you-get-a-microsoft-access-form-to-refresh-a-computed-column

Comment: Position your cursor on the first allowable line in that code: `blnUpdateSwitch = False`.  Use the F9 to set a breakpoint --- you will see a red dot in the left-hand margin and the entire line should also be highlighted in red.  Then go back to the form and click the command button.  Your code will be in break (debug) mode.  Step through the code one line at a time with F8.  And see what's happening.

Comment: HansUp - my apologies - I understand stepping through the code/breakpoint - my question was "what" am I looking for - meaning the code seems executes without error, the controls and the underlying values dont refresh on screen..

Comment: Remou-
That did not seem to help - I tried specifically doing a component.refresh/requery as well.

Again - this worked before, in Access 2003 - with just the Me.Requery (at the subform level) So something must be different version-wise ?

Comment: So then are you saying you confirmed `Me.Requery` really does happen when you expect it to but that requery does not update the form's record set correctly --- doesn't pull in saved changes to existing rows, show newly added rows, and/or discard deleted rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `Me.Requery` to `Me.Form.Requery`

Also, you can do the same with `Me.Refresh` to `Me.Form.Refresh`